# Bitcoind crashes directly after starting

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, solo-mining

I'm am trying to solo mine. My first problem is when I try to launch bitcoin client as server with guiminer I get this error

```
Invalid -rpcallowip subnet specifications.* valid are a single ip.
```

I looked around and it seems that I need to open `bitcoind` and change my `rpcallowip` from what I understand.

My problem then is, when I try to open `bitcoind`, it pops up for 1 second then crashes. I have tried to run it as admin, I have downloaded a new wallet, but I couldn't get it to work.

From what I have seen my guess is it looks like rpcallowip=192.168.0.* I have seen I need to change it to rpcallowip=192.168.0.1/24. The problem is I don't know where to change it. Also I don't know if this is even the problem. I am trying to take this one step at a time. .

I thought it was in bitcoin-di. And like I was saying every time I try to load it, it crashes.

My goal is to get guiminer to solo farm with bitcoin core as my wallet. I thought it would be an easy process.

I'm on windows 8.1 with bitcoin core v0.10.2. Using guiminer. I set up with slosh pool and got that to work. My gpu is not strong enough to do any good tho so I figured I would give a shot with solo.

I'm not sure of I'm way off. Where so I go to change it?

Thank you for the response.

Comment: Are you specifying several IP's? if so, use several rpcallowip= entries. In general, they should look like rpcallowip=127.0.0.1  or rpcallowip=192.168.0.1/24

Answer (score 2):

Well I figured it out. I had to find my bitcoin.config file. I opened it with note pad and changed rpcallowip=* to rpcallowip=192.168.0.1/24

I was trying to do that in bitcoind. Thanks to the guy who replied and thanks to whoever edited my post :)